# Adding a prefix or postfix to a Word 2013 quotation source

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013, field-codes, bibliography

I am using the German version of Word 2013, so I am not absolutely sure, if "quotation source" is the term being used in the English version. I am talking about the automatic text field, one can get via "References" (German: "Verweise"), "Insert quotation" (German: "Zitat einfügen"). Then one gets a drop down menu with all the entries from the bibliography, one can pick one and then an automatic text field is inserted into the text.

After it is hopefully clear what I am talking about, here is the question:

I chose the citation style "ISO 690" that generates labels of the pattern "(author+year)" in round parentheses. Sometimes I have to append a prefix or suffix to the label, but this prefix/suffix must go into the parentheses. Is there any way I can do this? For example, I can add page numbers to the end of a quotation label via a special dialog box that appears after a right click onto the text field and choosing "Edit quote" (German: "Zitat bearbeiten").

But there are a lot more cases of optional pre-/suffixes than page numbers. I am looking for a general way to add pre-/suffixes.

Comment: Have you looked at creating a custom Bibliography Style? Not easy but very flexible. Articles: [Bibliography & Citations 101](http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-word/archive/2007/12/14/bibliography-citations-1011.aspx) and [Bibliography & Citations 102 – Building Custom styles](http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-word/archive/2009/04/29/bibliography-citations-102-building-custom-styles.aspx)